# a dynamic list creation inside popup

Tags: android, listview, popup

I am very new to Android.

Is it possible to implement a TextBox , Button and a dynamic list inside popup in Android.

Please help me in this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make a custom dialog of your own.
I've used following code in my java file

Dialog add_themedialog = new Dialog(addthemecontext);

```
             add_themedialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_new_theme);
             add_themedialog.setTitle("Add New Theme");
             final EditText et_entertheme = (EditText)add_themedialog.findViewById(R.id.et_dialog_addtheme);
             Button btn_addtheme  = (Button)add_themedialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialogaddtheme);
             Button btn_canceltheme = (Button)add_themedialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_canceltheme);
```

The xml file add_new_theme contains a textbox,an edittext and 2 buttons..

Ask me if any thing is not clear or if you want complete source code for it. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I got it. I created a List view in Popups xml and assigned List adapter pointer of other class (xml) to that popup List view.